# Set a variable property from an object in PHP

Tags: php, json, oop, object

I have an "obj" object and a "str" string.
How do i set the $str property from "obj"?
This is my try:

```
$jsonStr = '{"foo":"bar","number":1}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);
$property = $_GET["prop"];
$jsonObj->$property = "value";
file_put_contents("OUT",json_encode($jsonObj));
```

It always outputs "{}"!

Note: Please sorry for bad english, i'm not a native english speaker.

EDIT:
I've tried to var_dump() every single variable in the code.

- **$_GET["prop"]** is `"foo"`
- **$jsonObj** actually IS `object(stdClass)#1 (1) {["foo"]:"value", ["number"]:1}`

so the error is in `file_put_contents("OUT",json_encode($jsonObj));`
...

EDIT 2:
I've found the error!
In the real code, i had written

```
$jsonStr = '{"foo":"bar","number":1}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);
$property = $_GET["prop"];
$jsonObj->$property = "value";
file_put_contents("OUT",json_encode(      ---->$jsonStr<----- ERROR! ));
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you sure is that all your code? As @AlexanderMadyuskin said your code is working correctly.

Comment: $jsonObj->$property = "value"; what's this ?... why you are using a statement like this ..

Comment: I'm using it to save JS variables in files using PHP and javascript. The client does something like set.php?prop=foo&value=bar. They're all saved in a single JSON file. To get them, the user calls get.php?prop=foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
file_put_contents("OUT",json_encode($jsonObj));
```

instead of

```
file_put_contents("OUT",json_encode($jsonStr));
```

The code actually works!
It was an spelling error.